Do you mind if with continuous tenses
I often see such sentences:

Do you mind if I smoke

I fully understand 1. What if we changed "I smoke" to "I am smoking". Does it make sense?

Do you mind if I am smoking

Whar if I want to say that I will be doing something before another event. Is then continuous fine

Do you mind if I am smoking when she comes


The "if" is an important word. "Do you mind that I'm smoking" is fine. The "if" creates a hypothetical—an imaginary possibility—and generally that's a job for infinitives.

All of these are questions, so they require a question mark (?).
(1) is asking permission to light a cigarette (i.e. the speaker isn't smoking yet).
If the speaker is already smoking, if is not appropriate. They would ask "Do you mind me smoking?", "Does the smoke bother you?" or similar.
As to (3), it might be more appropriate to ask "Will she mind if I am smoking when she comes?"

what about "Would you mind if I was smoking". Is it the same as 2 so incorrect or it works differently?

Yes, "Would you mind if I was smoking?" is similar to (2) in that it is not a request for permission but a hypothetical question.  It's not 'grammatically wrong', just not something that anyone would say.
